# Error while installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, boot, kernel

I have the same question as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360489/error-when-installing-13-10). I installed Ubuntu on an external hard drive using [Universal Ubuntu Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). When I booted with this USB plugged in, it showed a purple screen and then this error:

```
cannot open root device "null" or unknown block 0,0" 
"please append a correct root/boot option" 
"kernel panic- not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs unknown block-(0,0)".
```

What might be the cause of this error? I downloaded ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso from the [official site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc). It cannot be problem with architecture as suggested in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360489/error-when-installing-13-10/#comments-360489) because, I used the same architecture .iso file to install Ubuntu 13.04.

OS: Windows 8 without UEFI firmware

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted or write your own answer if you have a workaround.

Comment: That was a workaround. Not a solution to the problem, and I don't know if we get the same error while installing 13.04. It was by luck that I had it installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same error when I tried to install ubuntu 13.10 from DVD to dual boot windows 7 with UEFI in Bios.

I downloaded the 13.10 iso and then burn image to DVD. left DVD in drive and restarted PC.

Comment: I kind of bypassed the problem. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 first and then upgraded to 13.10.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? It looks like a "me too" comment.

Answer (score 0):

If u have Windows 8 but it was not preinstalled u should still be able to use WUBI which should be on the installation media.  Also, u can try to redownload and burn the iso.  that is what i did when i had a problem and it worked.  If u have any questions plz email me: darthmaulyou@gmail.com

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to download the iso again. But, what is the reason for that error?

Comment: I downloaded it and tried again, but the same error popped up.